# Embedding charts from azure log analytics work spaces in web application

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitor-workbooks

I want to embed charts created in azure log analytics work space in my react based application. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe currently it's not a supported feature to embed charts created in azure log analytics work space in web application. You may have to consume API's like https://dev.loganalytics.io/ or [Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.operationalinsights/Invoke-AzOperationalInsightsQuery?view=azps-4.2.0).

[Here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-azure-monitor-log-analytics/suggestions/32623598-embedding-log-analytics-solutions-to-third-party-w) is a related feature request. However, if interested, you may also raise direct feedback in [this](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/267889-log-analytics) UserVoice / feedback forum. Responsible product group / feature team would check feasibility of the raised feature request, prioritize against existing feature backlog and add in roadmap as appropriate.

Once feedback is created, you may upvote it and other features that are of interest. We would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.

Comment: Thank you .. this helps